# Is the city of Marinaleda a socialst utopia?

Tags: economics, politics

According to [this article](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2013/oct/20/marinaleda-spanish-communist-village-utopia) and many [many](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/05/26/world/europe/26spain.html?_r=2&pagewanted=all&) [others](http://www.livetravelenjoy.com/a-city-where-everyone-works-there-is-no-police-and-the-salary-is-1200-euros/), the Spanish city of Marinaleda is a socialist utopia.

The article claims that the mayor and city organizes raids against the local grocery stores to steal food for the poor, provide affordable housing and working at the cities communal farms. The morality of this, I leave to a lesser forum, what I'm intersted in is weather this is actually true.

Is there really low unemployment compared to the rest of spain?
Is the city mounting a pile of debt?
Are the heavily dependent on subsidies?

Comment: Neither of the first two articles that you referenced includes the word "raid", "grocery", nor "steal". Please use a direct quote (copy and paste) to quote the sentences or paragraph[s] which contains the 'claim' that you're skeptical of and want to question.

Comment: It isn't clear what the claim is. Utopia (and communism) is too poorly defined to decide if they have been achieved. Pick a claim from the article, quote it specifically, and ask if it is true. (Note: The article talks about communism, not socialism - another reason to quote the article itself.)

Comment: (The third article you referenced is uavailable with a 'resource limit exceeded' message from its web host).

Comment: I found the paragraph in the first article which describes "expropriations from supermarkets". Still, is that the question: are you asking whether that event happened, in history? Or are you asking about current unemployment etc.? It would be too much to ask people here to fact check every sentence in the articles.

Comment: I think ChrisW is referring to "They marched into supermarkets and took bread, rice, olive oil and other basic supplies, and donated them to food banks for Andalusians who could not feed themselves." This is clearly evidence supporting the claim that they did in fact steal food, although whether this was a one-off incident or "raids" as written is unclear.

Comment: http://www.elmundo.es/elmundo/2012/08/07/andalucia_sevilla/1344335915.html Spanish article on the mayor stealing food from a supermarket